# Default dark mode in tailwind css

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have default dark mode in tailwind css and next.js file. I want to change it in light mode. What to do? Why it is default dark mode in next.js file?

This is my config file and how to change the mode from dark to light?What to do to change it as light?

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
   
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  
}
export default config
```

Comment: Could [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode) be of help?

Comment: There is no "default dark mode" in Tailwind. By default, it uses the system settings. You can switch to class-based strategy, ie. you'd have a `dark` (customizable) class on your `html` element to toggle dark mode.